# Nearest neighbour Library for JavaScript

Tags: javascript, knn, flann

I need to perform the kNN algorithm on a bunch of sequences in JavaScript. I've come across the FLANN library for doing this however it is a C++ library and only contains bindings for MATLAB, Python and C. Is there a library which provides better use with JavaScript? If not, is there a way I can use the FLANN library for my script?

Answer (score 1):

A quick google search turned up this library, it was intended for use with node but I looked at the source and it seems fine for running in the browser or wherever. https://github.com/aschuch/node-nearest-neighbor.

If you're not using AMD you might need to rearrange things a bit.

Answer (score 1):

I create this Javascript library ([knn-js](https://github.com/study-ml/knn-js)), you can take a look.
Follow the readme file, you can set it up locally.

[image]